# How to get the .org domains from an array in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have an array with html tags, texts, etc. I would like to get the .org domains only from the list.

My code is not working:

```
<?php

$list = htmlentities(file_get_contents('list.html'));

preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+(.org)$/", $list, $matches);

var_dump ($matches);
?>
```

Comment: If a hyphen appears in a character class (between square brackets) then the hyphen must be the final character in that class. So try swapping the position of the period and the hyphen. Other than that, maybe give examples of what you're working with, as it's not very clear.

Comment: If you want preg_match to treat `^` and `$` as the beginning and the end of one line rather then whole string, you should set `m` modifier: `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+(.org)$/m"`. Does it help?

Comment: The content: http://pastebin.com/MRtS3s7y I would like to get the .org domains in an array.

lazyhammer: the result is `array(0) { }`

Comment: Couldn't you please post contents of `list.html` or at least some part of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$list = "google.com
    http://d.org
    google.org
    <ul>
        <li>www.yahoo.co.uk</li>
        <li>http://www.bsdflj.org.uk</li>
        <li>nsdfljsdf.org</li>
    </ul>";

preg_match_all("~([a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.org)[^\.]~s", $list, $matches);
var_dump ($matches[1]);
```

$list is what I tested it with.

Output of var_dump():

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "d.org"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "google.org"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "nsdfljsdf.org"
}
```